# Неправильное открытие JFrame при обработке слушателя

Tags: java, swing

```
MainJava.jTabPeople.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
           ...
        }
    });
```

В программе происходит открытие окна `JFrame` при нажатие на какой-либо элемент `JTable`, но дело в том, что этот слушатель реагирует и на нажатия на другие кнопки, в результате чего при повторном щелчке по элементу `JTable` открывается столько же окон `JFrame`, сколько до этого было сделано щелчков по другим кнопкам `JButton`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так.Здесь проверяется двойной клик по строке таблицы

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
                if (me.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1 &&  me.getClickCount() == 2) {
                    //номер выделенной строки в таблице
                    int rowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
                    if (rowIndex < 0) return;
                    //номер строки в модели
                    rowIndex = table.convertRowIndexToModel( rowIndex );
                    //получение значения из нужной ячейки
                    String val = table.getModel().getValueAt( rowIndex, columnId ).toString();

                    //открываете то что нужно

                }
            }
        });
```